# Fail to convert wsdl file to java code

Tags: java, webserver

I want to connect to my .net web server from android, I tried to convert server wsld file to java code but when I convert it by intelliJ plugin some classes are empty just like this `public class Recognition{}` any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wsimport.exe, which you can find in the "bin" library of your jdk.

Comment: open a command line, go to the directory of the wsimport.exe just type wsimport.exe and you will see the complete usage manual.

/wsimport.exe -s [generatedSourceDir] mywsdl.wsdl

should generate the java sources in the folder generatedSourceDir, copy the generated sources into your project, and you are done.

Comment: There's a good tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/

Comment: I did it, but some classes are still empty

Comment: so I guess your wsdl is broken, sorry

Comment: so how should I connect to web server? any other way?

Comment: try re-generating the wsdl

Comment: I tried and still some functions and fields are not in my classes

Comment: can you please share your wsdl ? I can try it but you need to wait for about 10 hours

Comment: you can see wsdl here `http://amirarcane.persiangig.com/NevisaWcfServiceLibrary.wsdl`

Comment: i got connection errors trying to use wsimport and suspected that your wsdl imports a xsd file. And yes its there.

http://11.12.13.174:8732/NevisaWcfServiceLibrary/?xsd=xsd1

Are you sure this xsd file is reachable and correct? Because its necessary

Comment: connection error? does converting wsdl have any work with connection?

Comment: yeah , not necessary for every wsdl but in your case the code generator is trying to get the imported xsd file from the addres above.

Comment: I checked it, the xsd file is ok and reachable, what to do?

Comment: im out of ideas mate, sorry